# How do I reenable Unity after reinstalling the nvidia drivers?

Tags: 11.04, unity, nvidia

Yesterday I upgraded to 11.04 and I found out the new Linux kernel 2.6.38 did not work. The maverick kernel however did. Searching at askubuntu I found some tips which suggested to disable quiet splash in the grub config (`/etc/default/grub`).

I supposed it had something to do with the video driver, so I disabled the nvidia proprietary driver and rebooted. This didn't really work and eventually I ended up with a the non-graphical tty1.

With `startx` I tried to start the graphical environment again, but this resulted in an error like:

```
Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
```

After that I booted in recovery mode and reinstalled the nvidia driver again, after the classic gnome worked again, but Unity doesn't work yet. Also in classic all (compiz) effects are disabled.

I guess I have to get that working again and Unity will work after that too, question is: how?

Comment: I also tried `compiz --replace` (and `unity --replace`) which had this output: http://pastie.org/private/ula73fntuxl9wvht7kkug It looks like opengl is failing.

Comment: It seems I'm using nouveau now, which doesn't really work with compiz yet... I didn't mange to switch to nvidia properly though.

Comment: I tried these steps: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia but I cannot find the linux-headers-2.6.35 in the repository anymore. I'm using that kernel because the 2.6.38 didn't boot at all.

Comment: Why 2.6.38 didn't boot? What are messages in console and logs?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled for a while in a similar spot. Ulimately my problem was that I hadn't installed the latest Nvidia drivers like I thought I had. Execute the following:

$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version

*NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86 Kernel Module  **270.41.06**  Mon Apr 18 14:54:25 PDT 2011
GCC version:  gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4)*

If you are seeing 173 or 185 in the output, you have an older version of the Nvidia driver installed. Older versions don't work that well - I found that out the hard way.

If this is your problem, launch "Additional Drivers" via the Gnome/System->Administration menu. It should allow you to choose to install the "current version". Choose to do that.

Comment: I think it will not work with 2.6.35 kernel

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking [compizconfig-settings-manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/compizconfig-settings-manager) is the package you're looking for...

Comment: I already have ccsm installed, and the Unity and other plugins are all enabled, so I don't think that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where Unity wouldn't work but Gnome would. I resolved this by logging in under Ubuntu (unity) and then pulled up ccsm. In ccsm disabling Gnome Compatibility and enabling Unity worked for me. Hope this helps.